# Super gif is showing 2 iterations of the gif despite loop is set to off

Tags: javascript, animated-gif

I have this code:

```
function gifattack() {
 var gifimg = document.getElementById('gifimg');
 var rub = new SuperGif({ gif: gifimg, progressbar_height: 0, loop_mode:false } );

 rub.load();
}


gifattack();

<div id="cont">
 <img id="gifimg" src="https://i.giphy.com/media/fDO2Nk0ImzvvW/200w.gif">
</div>
```

See the fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/dmno4qxb/2/

Notice how the gif shows for its first loop like too fast, then for the second loop it shows normal and stops as it should according to the settings. So, what's with the first loop and how can I stop it from happening?

Comment: Can you provide the URL directly to supergif? I'd wager a guess that you see it once directly played in the IMG tag, and a second time because supergif renders it anew.

Comment: you mean this https://github.com/buzzfeed/libgif-js ?